# Cannot replace nodes after using TreeWalker

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to replace the current text nodes with `span` nodes.
I have made this JS code but it does not work:

```
var EditorElement_Content;
var ContentElement_TreeWalker;
//
ContentElement_TreeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(EditorElement_Content, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
while (ContentElement_TreeWalker.nextNode()) {
    var ReplacementNode = document.createElement("span");
    ReplacementNode.appendChild(ContentElement_TreeWalker.currentNode);
    ContentElement_TreeWalker.currentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(ReplacementNode, ContentElement_TreeWalker.currentNode);
}
```

Also, the Web explorer console returns this: `HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy`

What am I doing wrong and why?

Thanks in advance.